# Show that $S\subseteq c_{0}$ is precompact if $S$ is bounded, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup\left\{|x_{n}|: x=(x_{n})\in S\right\}=0.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

We consider the vector space $c_{0}:=\left\{x=(x_{n})\subset\mathbb{C}\:\left|\:x_{n}\rightarrow 0\right.\right\}$ with norm
$\left\|x\right\|=\sup_{n}|x_{n}|$. Show that $S$ a subset of $c_{0}$ is precompact if it satisfies the following conditions:

**a)** $S$ is bounded, and

**b)** $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup\left\{|x_{n}|\:|\: x=(x_{n})\in S\right\}=0.$

**My attempt:** Let $\varepsilon>0$, then by **b)** and he fact that $S\subset c_{0}$ we have that there exists $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $|x_{n}|<\varepsilon/4$ for all $x\in S$. Therefore
$$\sup_{n\geq N}|x_{n}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4} \qquad \forall x\in S. \tag{*}$$
Note that for all $x,y\in S$ we have
$$\sup_{n\geq N}|x_{n}-y_{n}|\leq\sup_{n\geq N}|x_{n}|+\sup_{n\geq N}|y_{n}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{**}$$
We consider the following subset of $\mathbb{C}^{N-1}$
$$\widehat{S}=\left\{\mathbf{x}=(\mathbf{x}_{1},\ldots,\mathbf{x}_{N-1})\: \left|\: \exists x\in S \mbox{ such that }x_{1}=\mathbf{x}_{1},\ldots,x_{N-1}=\mathbf{x}_{N-1}\right. \right\}.$$
By hypothesis **a)** we know that $S$ is bounded, then there exists $M>0$ such that $\left\|x\right\|\leq M$, we consider the infty norm $\left\|\:\right\|_{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{C}^{N-1}$, then fora  all $\mathbf{x}\in \widehat{S}$ we have
$$\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|_{\infty}=\sup_{1\leq n\leq N-1}|\mathbf{x}_{n}|=\sup_{1\leq n\leq N-1}|x_{n}|\leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_{n}|=\left\|x\right\|\leq M.$$
Therefore, $\widehat{S}\subseteq \overline{\mathcal{B}_{M}(0)}\subset \mathbb{C}^{N-1}$ (close ball of center $0$ and radius $M$), but we know that $\overline{\mathcal{B}_{M}(0)}$ is compact in $\mathbb{C}^{N-1}$, then is precompact, and we know that all subset of precompact set is precompact, then $\widehat{S}$ is precompact, then there exists $\mathbf{x}^{1},\ldots,\mathbf{x}^{m} \in \widehat{S}$ such that
 $$\widehat{S} \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{m}\mathcal{B}_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(\mathbf{x}^{k}).\tag{***}$$
But for each $\mathbf{x}_{k}$ there exists $x^{k}\in S$, considering $\mathcal{B}^{c_{0}}_{\varepsilon}(x^{k})$ the open ball of center $x^{k}$ of radius $\varepsilon$ in the normed vector space $c_{0}$ we want to show that
$$S\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{m}\mathcal{B}^{c_{0}}_{\varepsilon}(x^{k}).\tag{$\bigstar$}$$
In fact, let $x\in S$, then consider $\mathbf{x}=(x_{1},\ldots,x_{N})\in \mathbb{C}^{N-1}$, then $\mathbf{x}\in \widehat{S}$, then by (***) there exists $\mathbf{x^{j}}$ with $j\in\left\{1,\ldots,m\right\}$ such that $\mathbf{x}\in \mathcal{B}_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(\mathbf{x}^{j}) $, then 
$$\sup_{1\leq n\leq N-1}|x_{n}-x_{n}^{j}|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{****}$$
But by (**) we know that 
$$\sup_{n\geq N}|x_{n}-x_{n}^{j}|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{*****}$$ 
Therefore, by (****) and (*****) we have 
$$\left\|x-x^{j} \right\|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_{n}-x_{n}^{j}|\leq \sup_{1\leq n\leq N-1}|x_{n}-x_{n}^{j}|+\sup_{1\leq n\leq N-1}|x_{n}-x_{n}^{j}|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$
Which shows ($\bigstar$).

**The questions:**

I would like to know if my proof is correct, in case it is not correct, I would like to know the mistakes.

I feel that my proof is a little extensive, I would like to know another proof for this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. However, I must say that the last bit is a tad odd, in the sense that using 'triangle inequality' for that supremum is... very weird, and I'd say even a bit nonsensical. Instead, it seems more natural to use the following:

> **Lemma:** Let $S=A\cup B$. If $\sup A \leq c$ and $\sup B\leq c$, then $\sup S \leq c$.
>
> Notice the union need not be disjoint.

*Proof:* Indeed, if we had $\sup S> c$, there would be some $s\in S$ with $s>c$.
Since $S=A\cup B$, we would have $s\in A$, which violates $\sup A\leq c$, or $s\in B$, which violates $\sup B\leq c$.
In either case, there is a contradiction, so we must have $\sup S\leq c$ as claimed. $\square$

This would slightly simplify your proof, in that the reader would only need to keep track of $\epsilon$, rather than $\epsilon/2$.

---

Other than that, a stylistic approach I would recommend is defining $\widehat{S}$ in terms of the ovbious projection $\pi: c_0\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{N-1}$. To me, this feels more natural/reads more fluidly, and would probably save a few words later when you talk about $\widehat{S}=\pi(S)$ later.